# Why is this index out of range? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, indexoutofrangeexception

```
           For k As Integer = 0 To (input.Length - 1)
                If input(input.Length - 1) <> " " Then
                    letter &= input(k)
                ElseIf input(k) = " " And ((k = 0) Or (input(k - 1) <> " ")) Then
                    For a As Integer = lastspace To k
                        letter &= input(a)
                    Next
           Next
```

letter and input have been Dimmed as a string, with input being equal to a console.readline()
Every time i run the program, i get an "IndexOutOfRangeException" error on the first ElseIf. I just started VB so im not really sure what's gone wrong here, or how to fix it. 
I tried to fix it with the "k=0 or" but it didnt help. Any ideas?

Comment: when `k=0`, `input(k - 1)` will be illegal

Comment: that's what i intended to rule out with the "or", is there any other way of ruling it out?

Comment: Could you explain what are trying to accomplish with this code? It feels like an hand made solution for a problem where a more simple solution could be found using standard NET classes.

Comment: im trying to convert a morse code input, using dots and dashes, into letters of the alphabet. the rest of the code works fine but as i said, im new to vb so im not sure what a standard NET class is. This section of the code was supposed to split the input into each morse "letter" using spaces as an indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Or operator in VB.NET doesn't short circuit the evaluation of the expression. So your Or doesn't block the evaluation of k-1 when k is 0

You should use

```
ElseIf input(k) = " " And ((k = 0) OrElse (input(k - 1) <> " ")) Then
```

From MSDN [Or Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)

> In a Boolean comparison, the Or operator always evaluates both
>   expressions, which could include making procedure calls. The OrElse
>   Operator (Visual Basic) performs short-circuiting, which means that if
>   expression1 is True, then expression2 is not evaluated.

From MSDN [OrElse Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)

> A logical operation is said to be short-circuiting if the compiled
>   code can bypass the evaluation of one expression depending on the
>   result of another expression. If the result of the first expression
>   evaluated determines the final result of the operation, there is no
>   need to evaluate the second expression, because it cannot change the
>   final result. Short-circuiting can improve performance if the bypassed
>   expression is complex, or if it involves procedure calls.

Comment: thanks so much. that fixed the error. i had no idea `OrElse` was a thing. thank you

Comment: Also looking at your comment above, I suggest to look at the various overload of the string method called [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When k=0, input(k - 1) results in the array index being -1, which is out of range.

Comment: yes but the "or" should make it ignore input(k -1) if k = 0.